# How to detect touch end event for UIButton?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, touch

I want to handle an event occurs when **UIButton** touch is ended. I know that UIControl has some events implementing touches (UIControlEventTouchDown, UIControlEventTouchCancel, etc.). But I can't catch any of them except **UIControlEventTouchDown** and **UIControlEventTouchUpInside**.

My button is a subview of some UIView. That UIView has **userInteractionEnabled** property set to **YES**.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set 'action targets' for your button according to the `ControlEvents`

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

Example:

```
[yourButton addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(methodTouchDown:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[yourButton addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(methodTouchUpInside:)
 forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)methodTouchDown:(id)sender{

   NSLog(@"TouchDown");
}
-(void)methodTouchUpInside:(id)sender{

  NSLog(@"TouchUpInside");
}
```

Comment: Oh, it works great. My inattention played a cruel joke with me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks . This works. But issue comes if the user drags while touching. TouchUpInside not getting called during that tym :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own custom class that extends `UIButton`.
your header file should look like this.

```
@interface customButton : UIButton
{
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

then make your implementation file

Comment: Unfortunately, my senior programmer forbade to create a new class. But this solution also works properly

Answer (score 3):

@Ramshad's accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667813/3659227) in **Swift 3.0** syntax
using following method of *UIControl* class

```
open func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents)
```

Example:

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.touchDownEvent), for: .touchDown)
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.touchUpEvent), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])

func touchDownEvent(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("TouchDown")
}

func touchUpEvent(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("TouchUp")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 version:**

```
 let btn = UIButton(...)

 btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyView.onTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

 func onTap(_ sender: AnyObject) -> Void {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is more easy

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressOnButton = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressOnButton:)];
longPressOnButton.delegate = self;
btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[btn addGestureRecognizer:longPressOnButton];



- (void)longPressOnButton:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    // When you start touch the button
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
       //start recording
    }
    // When you stop touch the button
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        //end recording
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add IBOutlets for UIButton with Events `TouchDown:` and Primary Action `Triggered:`

```
- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"This will trigger when button is Touched");
}

- (IBAction)primaryActionTriggered:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"This will trigger Only when touch end within Button Boundary (not Frame)");
}
```